# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while implementing Room Android

Tags: android, android-room, android-reflection

```
@Dao
interface MyStuffDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM mystuff WHERE mid = :mid")
    fun selectByMid(mid: Long): ArrayList<MyStuff>

    @Insert
    fun insertMyStuff(mid: Long, name: String)

    @Delete
    fun deleteMyStuffName(mid: Long, name: String)

    @Delete
    fun deleteMyStuff(mid: Long)
}
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "mystuff")
data class MyStuff (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val seq: Long,

    // this name is used in dao as column name
    @ColumnInfo(name = "mid") val mid: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") var name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "created_at") var createdAt: String
)
```

```
@Database(entities = [MyStuff::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun myStuffDao(): MyStuffDao

    companion object {
        const val DB_NAME = "MyDatabase.db"
        private var INSTANCE: MyDatabase? = null
        fun getMyDatabase(context: Context?): MyDatabase? {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context!!,
                    MyDatabase::class.java,
                    DB_NAME
                ).build()
            }
            return INSTANCE
        }

        fun destroyInstance() {
            INSTANCE = null
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

I've changed gradle, but they all didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can not declare `@Insert` or `@Delete` with custom parameter it should take entity instead like that.

```
@Insert
fun insertMyStuff(entity: MyStuff)

@Delete
fun deleteMyStuffName(entity: MyStuff)

@Delete
fun deleteMyStuff(entity: MyStuff)
```

More detail you can check [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Insert)

> All of the parameters of the Insert method must either be classes annotated with Entity or collections/array of it.

Comment: Are you sure? Then, what if I want to delete one row with only name?

Comment: Sure, you can check here https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Delete. But you can create dummy object when delete and pass id, if only name you should using @Query("DELETE FROM FROM mystuff WHERE name: = :name")

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exception. In my case it was because I'd forgotten to add **@Entity** to one of my model classes, e.g.

```
@Entity
data class Category(
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: As you can see my question, I had that annotation.